# Magento extension dropdown option in configuration dont work

Tags: magento

I build a magento extension and I am trying to add in its configuration page a dropdown to choose one from product id or product sku so i can display in success page. I alter my code a lot of times but I can only get 1 of them working. How I can add the attribute codes for its value? I need to set product_id, sku and if its possible a custom field for its setup needs. Here are the parts I think you need.

**app/design/frontend/base/default/template/vendor/success.phtml**

```
'product_id': '<?php echo $_item->getData($this->getProductIdField())?>',
```

**app/code/community/Vendor/Package/Model/System/Config/Source/Productid.php**

```
class Vendor_Package_Model_System_Config_Source_Productid
{
    public function toOptionArray()
{
    return array(
        array('value' => 'entity_id', 'label'=>Mage::helper('vendor_package')->__('Product ID')),
        array('value' => 'sku', 'label'=>Mage::helper('vendor_package')->__('Product SKU')),
    );
}
```

}

**app/code/community/Vendor/Package/Block/Package.php**

```
public function getProduct()
{
    return Mage::registry('current_product');
}
public function getProductIdField()
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('vendor_package/ecommerce/product_id') != false ? Mage::getStoreConfig('vendor_package/ecommerce/product_id') : 'sku';
}
```

**app/code/community/Vendor/Package/etc/config.xml**

```
<default>
    <vendor_package>
        <ecommerce>
            <transaction_id>id</transaction_id>
            <product_id>sku</product_id>
        </ecommerce>
    </vendor_package>
</default>
```

**app/code/community/Vendor/Package/etc/system.xml**

```
                    <product_id>
                        <label>Product Id</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <source_model>vendor_package/system_config_source_productid</source_model>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </product_id>
```

Comment: In your examples, `Blabla` seems to represent the vendor *and* the package. I assume this is a mistake you've made while trying to hide your real vendor and package, but it would never work like this - if it's inaccurate, please update your question.

Comment: Ok now is updated, corrected and case sensitive @RobbieAverill